# Programmatically Call on a mobile number without user interaction and without user confirmation prompt in iOS

Tags: ios

How to call on a mobile number without user interaction and without user confirmation prompt in iOS using Swift / Objective C?

Comment: i think it's not possible

Comment: Apple are quite strict on security and asking for permission to things on a users behalf. They would not just allow you to make calls without any prompt to the user i think

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for phone calls, but for VoIP is:

> To make an outgoing call, an app requests a CXStartCallAction object from its CXCallController object. The action consists of a UUID to uniquely identify the call and a CXHandle object to specify the recipient.

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit)

Comment: still possible to make phone call over VoIP without user interaction?